# How to pass RequestContext as an optional third argument to render_to_response

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am having some problems with csrf tokens and I believe the issue relates to using a SessionWizardview `done()` method which uses `render_to_response` and therefore a Context instance rather than RequestContext. [From the Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext)

> If you’re using Django’s render_to_response() shortcut to populate a
>   template with the contents of a dictionary, your template will be
>   passed a Context instance by default (not a RequestContext). To use a
>   RequestContext in your template rendering, pass an optional third
>   argument to render_to_response(): a RequestContext instance. Your code
>   might look like this:
>
> ```
> def some_view(request):
>     # ...
>     return render_to_response('my_template.html',
>                               my_data_dictionary,
>                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
> ```

Apparently RequestContext always uses `django.core.context_processors.csrf` From the same documntation:

> In addition to these, RequestContext always uses
>   django.core.context_processors.csrf. This is a security related
>   context processor required by the admin and other contrib apps, and,
>   in case of accidental misconfiguration, it is deliberately hardcoded
>   in and cannot be turned off by the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
>   setting.

But I am having trouble attaching/passing the optional third argument to my 'done()' method

```
class SurveyWizardOne(SessionWizardView):                      
    def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
    ....
    ....

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):   
        return render_to_response('Return_to_AMT.html', {
            'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I use the above I get the below error when the user submits the form.

> Exception Value:   global name 'request' is not defined

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty basic Python: you can't reference an object that doesn't exist in the current scope.

Luckily, all class-based views which inherit from the base View class set the request as an instance variable, which means you can reference it as `self.request`. Also note there is a shorter `render` shortcut which uses RequestContext internally, and which takes the request as the initial parameter. So:

```
return render(self.request, 'Return_to_AMT.html', {
        'form_data': [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list],            
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, you came to my rescue again and nice tip on the `render`.